# Need paypal collection fees/charge storage location for orders

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I'm working on magento 1.9 CE and using paypal standard. I need data of fees charged for sales(done through paypal) and have searched long to find out if they are stored in database. I know that the following link provides the numbers https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees.

I would like to know if they are stored in database so that I can automate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a really long research, found out that it is the paypal model file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php in magento root directory where we need to do the following  :

Method/function is _registerPaymentCapture.Here, use the following code :

**$paypal_fee = $this->getRequestData('mc_fee');**

under the code

**$payment = $this->_order->getPayment();**

Additionally where to store :

This should be stored in table **sales_flat_invoice**. Add a column to store.

Code for the same :

in the same method, there is code **if ($invoice && !$this->_order->getEmailSent())** after this block, use a mySql query to update the table :

**if($invoice){**

// table is sales_flat_invoice
// where increment_id = $invoice->getIncrementId();

mySql query goes here...

**}**

Comment: This might not be the best way but so far no issues as it is simple query based.